# while read loop + create aproccess in the while loop

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

The following test script has a problem. When I add the line `(sleep 5 )&` in the script then the `while read` loop does not read all lines from the file, but only prints the first line.

But when I remove the `( sleep 5 )&` from the script, then the script prints all lines as defined in the file.

Why the `( sleep 5 )&` causes this?

And how to solve the problem? I want to create a new process (for which the sleep is just an example) in the while loop.

```
$ more test

#!/bin/ksh 
while read -r line ; do 
echo $line
( sleep 5 )&   
RESULT=$!
sleep 1
kill $RESULT
done < file


$ more file
123 aaa
234 bbb
556 ccc
```

Comment: Which version of ksh are you using ? I dont see it on ksh93t+ just like Gilles mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The code you provides runs and prints each line in the file.

Since you are not waiting for the

```
( sleep 5 ) &
```

child process, it has no effect on process execution.  Is this the EXACT code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in a specific version of ksh. I'm getting the same effect from ksh 93s+, but not from bash, ash, pdksh, zsh or ksh 93t+.

Answer (score 0):

This KornShell (ksh) script works fine for me with this version:

- `echo $KSH_VERSION`

  - `@(#)MIRBSD KSH R48 2013/08/16`

**soExample.ksh :**

```
#!/bin/ksh 

#Initialize Variables
file=file
fileContent="123\taaa\n234\tbbb\n556\tccc"

#Function to create File with Input
#Params: 1}Directory 2}File
createBlankFileHere(){
    echo "Entering createFileHere"
    > ${1}
    echo "Exiting createFileHere"
}

#Function to create File with Input
#Params: 1}File 2}String to write to FileName
createFileWithInputHere(){
    echo "Entering createFileWithInputHere"
    > ${1}
    #-e means 'enable interpretation of backslash escapes
    echo -e ${2} >> ${1}
    #print ${2} >> ${1}
    echo "Exiting createFileWithInputHere"
}

#Function to 
#Params: 1} File
readLine(){
    echo "Entering readLine"
    while read -r line ; do 
    echo ${line}
    ( sleep 5 )&   
    RESULT=${!}
    sleep 1
    kill ${RESULT}
    done < ${1}
    echo "Exiting readLine"
}

#-----------
#---Main----
#-----------
echo "Starting: ${PWD}/${0} with Input Parameters: {1: ${1} {2: ${2} {3: ${3}"
createFileWithInputHere ${file} ${fileContent} #function call#
readLine ${file} #function call#
echo "Exiting: ${PWD}/${0}"
```

**soExample.ksh Output:**

```
user@foo /tmp
$ ksh soExample.ksh
Starting: /tmp/soExample.ksh with Input Parameters: {1:  {2:  {3:
Entering createFileWithInputHere
Exiting createFileWithInputHere
Entering readLine
123 aaa
234 bbb
556 ccc
Exiting readLine
Exiting: /tmp/soExample.ksh
```